# Trying do draw a couple of function with TikZ/PGFPLOTS

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having trouble drawing some functions:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=major,ymax=2500,xmax=2500]
          \addplot[no markers, blue, restrict y to domain=0:1714, samples=30000] { 2412 - 2.795e-10*(x^4)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Code runs through fine but there's no function appearing, only the coordinate system and grid.

Works fine now! -> see below.

What doesn't work is this function:

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=major,ymax=10000,xmax=10000,xmin=0,ymin=0]
          \addplot[no markers, blue, domain=0:10000, samples=10, % you can make it larger 
          %restrict y to domain=0:1714,% but this filter the results anyway
          samples=300 
          ] { 93231-3.552e-10*x^5};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code samples should produce the following error messages:

> Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away) on input line 11.
>
> Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 12.

So `pgfplots` actually informs you about the empty plotting range. You can fix this by providing a `domain` range of x values to be plotted.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=major,ymax=2500,xmax=2500]
          \addplot[no markers, blue, domain=1200:1800, % you can make it larger 
          restrict y to domain=0:1714,% but this filter the results anyway
          samples=300 % I reduced the number of samples to speed-up the compilation
          ] { 2412 - 2.795e-10*(x^4)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also in your second example you are filtering to a y range, so that no points are left to be plotted.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=major,ymax=100000,xmax=10000,xmin=0,ymin=0]
          \addplot[no markers, blue, domain=0:1000, %s
          restrict y to domain=0:100000,% 
          samples=301 
          ] { 93231-3.552e-10*x^5};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. So in the end is was just the samples? I have another function, that doesn't work. I edited my question.

Comment: @SF6 I updated my answer with your second example. Feel free to accept it ;-)